# Can I interpret `< file1 cmd1` as `cmd1 file1`?

Tags: bash

I've been asked to re-create this command in C, with no additional information as to what cmd1 could be.

```bash
< file1 cmd1 | cmd2 > file2
```

My question resolves around the first character of this command: the `<`.

Let's ignore the command after the pipe, and pretend cmd1 is `cat`.

I can thus replace `< file1 cat` with `cat file1`, which is much easier to do in C. But is this approach valid when it comes to other commands?

I've tested both `cat` and `sed` with these two commands:

```bash
< Makefile cat
cat Makefile
```

And

```bash
< Makefile sed 'p'
sed 'p' Makefile
```

Both print out the same result. So is it safe to assume I can interpret `< file1 cmd1` as `cmd1 file1`?

Comment: No they aren't the same. Some commands may not interpret one of its arguments as input.

Comment: Redirection happens before command is exec()'d. I think what you'll have to do here is do a pipe-fork and in the first process, open file1 and replace fd0 with it. In the second process, open file2 and replace fd1 with it.

Comment: In any case, you'd need to handle the output redirection as an actual redirection, so trying to skip on the input one isn't going to help much.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Not to mention, you need to do both an input and an output redirection to make the pipe work.

Comment: Your question title contains backticks but the question body does not. Noting that backticks in the most popular shells have a special meaning, please clarify.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't.

While there are many programs, like most of the common text processing tools (`sed`, `cut`, `grep` etc.) that read the data to process from files listed as command line arguments, or read it from stdin if no files are given, that's not the case for all programs there are. Command line arguments are different from data provided via stdin, and it's wholly up to the program how to process them.

The obvious counterexamples are programs like `rm`, which don't read stdin at all, but even with ones where you might think the equivalence would hold, there are filter-like commands such as `tr` and `wc` which don't take a filename arg at all, or produces different output.

---

The command line syntax of `tr` is roughly:

```
tr [options] string1 [string2]
```

It doesn't take any filenames as arguments, but always reads its stdin.

Hence, turning

```
< file.txt tr abc xyz
```

into

```
tr abc xyz file.txt
```

will just produce an error.

---

As mentioned in the comments, `wc` is another common tool that also behaves differently, though it's a bit less extreme. With the filename given, it includes it in the output (even if there's only one, unlike with `grep`):

```
$ wc hello.txt 
       1       1       4 hello.txt
$ wc < hello.txt
       1       1       4
```

---

Also many programs take the filename `-` as an explicit instruction to read stdin, but the shell doesn't support that. So while `cat < -` reads a file called `-`, `cat -` reads from `cat`'s stdin, likely the terminal.

Comment: Also see: `wc`, the classic example of a program with different behaviour in the two cases

Comment: Also `<answers rm -i file` vs `rm -i file answers`...

Comment: See also `cat -` vs `< - cat`

Comment: Ah yes I see you point thanks a lot :), but you may want to correct `wc`, as I believe it does produce the same result... It should be `< hello.txt wc` in the second example

Comment: @HerbieVine, `< hello.txt wc` is the same as `wc < hello.txt` in Bourne-like shells. Both run `wc` which no argument (well strictly speaking with one argument, `argv[0[` being `wc`) and with fd 0 redirected on `hello.txt` opened in read-only mode. Redirections can appear anywhere on the command line.